# Is it possible to destroy a dispatched event

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3.

I've got a class named "UseBox" that dispatch an event.

If thisThing.buyable not event is dispatch and the child "Building" is visible whith 2 buildings visible and 2 not visible.

If thisThing.destructible then the event "upgradable" is dispatch and the child "Building" is visible whith 4 buildings visible.

The problem is that the dispatch "upgradable" is always on now.

Is it possible to destroy the event each time the child "Building" become visible ?

Thanx for your answers,

Here's my code :

UseBox

```
  public function UseBox(stageRef:Stage, thisThing:Object){
if (thisThing.buyable){
useButton.gotoAndStop("buy");
useButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyIt, false, 0, true);
}
    if (thisThing.destructible){
    this.gotoAndStop("upgrade");
    upgradeButton.buttonMode = true;
    upgradeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, upgradeIt, false, 0, true);
                }

    public function buyIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
                boxClicked();
                showBatiments();
                lookButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyIt);
            }
            public function upgradeIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
                boxClicked();
                showBatiments();
                        stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event("upgradable"));
                lookButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyIt);
            }
    private function showBatiments():void{
                Engine.batiments.visible = true;
                }
```

Oh, and my buidling.as code :

```
poulaillerPlusBtn.visible = false;
poulaillerImpossible.visible = true;
poulaillerBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poulaillerConstruction, false, 0, true);
stageRef.addEventListener("upgradable", checkConstruction, false, 0, true);


private function checkConstruction(Event):void{
            trace("I've heard upgradable");
            poulaillerPlusBtn.visible = true;
            poulaillerImpossible.visible = false;
            poulaillerPlusBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poulaillerAmelioration, false, 0, true);
            trace("on a vérifé, tu peux améliorer le batiment");
        }
```

So, if the event "upgradable" is heard, the function "checkConstruction" is called, else not.

But, once the event "upgradable" has been dispatched, it seems that it stay always dispatch so the function "checkConstruction" is always called when "Building" is visible...

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's really hard to read your English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but if your only looking to handle an event once, then once you've recieved it by `checkConstruction` being called, you can remove it from listening for the event again:

```
private function checkConstruction(Event):void{
    //Here, you would remove the function from listening to any more "upgradable" events being dispatched. 
    stageRef.removeEventListener("upgradable", checkConstruction);


    trace("I've heard upgradable");
    poulaillerPlusBtn.visible = true;
    poulaillerImpossible.visible = false;
    poulaillerPlusBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poulaillerAmelioration, false, 0, true);
    trace("on a vérifé, tu peux améliorer le batiment");
}
```